# How to convert PDF (it contains only tiff Images) to JPG Image in java

Tags: java, jpeg, pdfbox, tiff

When I try to convert a PDF (330 KB contains 3 tiff images) to JPG images each image is converted to very high size, total images is more than 1MB. How can one reduce the size back to 330 KB with good or high JPG image quality?

Extracting each PDF page and passing to jpgwriter.

```
PDPage pages = document.getPage(page);
BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page);
ImageWriter jpgWriter = 
ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(0.7f);

ImageOutputStream outputStream = createOutputStream(); 
jpgWriter.setOutput(outputStream);
IIOImage outputImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);
jpgWriter.write(bim, outputImage, jpgWriteParam);
jpgWriter.dispose();
```

Comment: Just don't convert to JPEG.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pdf to image using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519994/pdf-to-image-using-java)

Comment: No, I've tried with BufferedImage with and without DPI.
pdfRenderer.renderImage(page)
pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 72f)
pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pge, 72f, ImageType.RGB)

Comment: If these are b/w scans of text, then it is indeed a terrible idea to convert them to JPEG because such images are usually CCITT Fax G4 compressed (which you misidentify as "tiff") and this usually the best. All you can do is to play around with "setCompressionQuality".

Answer (score -1):

We have new methods and service providers which provide this feature as SAAS. PDF4me is best among them. You can use their JAVA library to do this easily. Please refer https://developer.pdf4me.com/docs/api/basic-functionality/create-image/ to get the library and to use it in JAVA.

--Thanks